# Rails - Show associated data on Index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm struggling to have a belongs_to model iterate correctly inside a partial in an index page.

**Classes:**

```
class Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :chapter_num,
  belongs_to :chapter
  #fields: :id, :name, :chapter_num
end

class County < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :county_num, :chapter_id
  has_many :counties
  #fields: :id, :name, :county_num, :chapter_id
end

class ChaptersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @chapters = Chapter.all
    @counties = County.all(:joins => :chapter, :select => "counties.*, chapters.id")
  end
end
```

**app/views/chapters/index.html.erb:**

```
<h1>Chapter Index</h1>
  <%= render @chapters %>
<br />
<%= link_to "Add a new Chapter", new_chapter_path, class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
```

**app/views/chapters/_chapter.html.erb:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span5 offset1"><h4><%= link_to chapter.name, edit_chapter_path(chapter.id) %></h4></div>
  <div class="span2"><h4><%= chapter.chapter_num %></h4></div>
</div>
<!-- here's where the problem starts -->
<% @counties.each do |county| %>
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4 offset1"><%= county.name %></div>
  <div class="span4 offset1"><%= county.county_num %></div>
  <div class="span2"><%= link_to 'edit', '#' %></div>
</div>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "New county", new_county_path %>
<hr>
```

The current code shows the screenshot below. The problem is it's iterating through all the counties, not just the counties associated with a given chapter. [image: Screenshot of Index view]

How do I add a chapter specific variable within the partial that will cause the counties to iterate based upon the `:chapter_id` field since I'm in the index view, not the show view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class ChaptersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @chapters = Chapter.all
    # @counties = County.all(:joins => :chapter, :select => "counties.*, chapters.id")
  end
end
```

View:

```
<% chapter.counties.each do |county| %>
```

Comment: That worked. Nothing like the obvious to remind me how green I am. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this would work for you:

```
<%= @chapters.each do |chapter| %>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="span5 offset1"><h4><%= link_to chapter.name, edit_chapter_path(chapter.id) %></h4></div>
      <div class="span2"><h4><%= chapter.chapter_num %></h4></div>
    </div

    <% chapter.counties.each do |county| %>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="span4 offset1"><%= county.name %></div>
          <div class="span4 offset1"><%= county.county_num %></div>
          <div class="span2"><%= link_to 'edit', '#' %></div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to "New county", new_chapter_county_path(chapter) %>
<% end %>
```

Note that the key is to understand that because each chapter has many counties, you should iterate through the counties of each chapter via `chapter.counties.each` which will give you only the counties that belong to that particular chapter.

Also note the different link_to path for creating a new county.  If you have your routes set up such that counties are nested under chapters, you should be able to do  `new_chapter_county_path(chapter)`

Comment: I just switched to nesting the County routes, but didn't have them nested at the time of the post. Your solution is right, but I also needed to remove the @counties assignment from the index definition as Valery Kvon pointed out above. Thanks!